# HTML changing display to block when user already cookied

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

HTML code :

```
<div id="popupID"/>
<div id="hid" style="display:none;">
<table style="background:white; box-shadow:0px 1px 1px 1px #CCC;">
<tr>
<td style=" background:#C30;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:30px; padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px; color:white; "><center>Step 1</center></td><td style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:white; padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;background:#060; font-size:30px;"><center>Step 2</center></td>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    

var beenherecookie = 'FE44been644';

var beenherebegin = document.cookie.indexOf(beenherecookie);

var isFirstTime = false;
var popupHandler = function(firstTime){
    if(firstTime){
        return "block";
    }
    else{
        return "none";
    }
}

if (beenherebegin >    -1){
    isFirstTime = false; 
    WriteCookie("FE44been644","yes");}
}
else{
    isFirstTime = true;
}

document.getElementById('popupID').style.display= popupHandler(isFirstTime);

</script>
```

This is my function to hide it with time limit :

```
//function showIt() {
//  document.getElementById("hid").style.display = "block";
//}
//setTimeout("showIt()", 300000); // 1000 is 1 second
```

So here's how I want it to work in a way.
When the user visit for the first time it the style of the display would be none.
Then the same time , the function will write a cookie in their browser where when the second time the user visit the same site , the style of the display would be block.
I can't figure out how to do so .
I would like the new user to come visit the site for the first time then it would set the none to block for at least 5 minutes so when again the user return to the page he doesn't need to wait and it will instead turn to block
Could someone help me out ?

Comment: Simpler: `var popupHandler = function (ft){ return ft ? "block" : "none"; }`

Comment: @Adelphia , i mean i'm working on it but doesn't work..
I would like the new user to come visit the site for the first time then it would set the none to block for at least 5 minutes so when again the user return to the page he doesn't need to wait and it will instead turn to block

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't the WriteCookie be used when it's isFirstTime = true?
not when it's false.
If it's first time, set the cookie. If they've been here already, no need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var cookieName = 'myCookie';

    if (document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName) > -1) {
        document.getElementById('popupID').style.display= "block";
    } else {
        //writecookie
        document.cookie=(cookieName+"=yes");
        //setTimeout... TODO
    }
</script>
```

Be careful in the way you test your code. No cookie will be written if you load your html page directly from your filesystem in your browser.